# axios delete request is not sending data field in config object

Tags: axios

I am trying to pass axios.delete('https://httpbin.org/delete',{data:"anything"});
but when I m inspecting the response, the data field is null or the request body in null. Is this the only way to send request body in delete method of axios

```
 axios.delete('https://httpbin.org/delete', {data:'gfghhhg'})
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response",response);

      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("error",e);
      })
```

[this is the response in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgbDl.jpg)

Comment: it was a problem with axios newer version